# Selenium ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt

Tags: selenium-webdriver

This method intermittently hangs on me not honoring the timeout at all.  Other times it times out when as far as I can tell it shouldn't... the iframe is there and loaded.  Then other times it works exactly how I expect it to.

Is there a better method to use?  It feels like exactly the method I would be interested in.I've only noticed it on nested iFrames (normally about 3 deep).

Comment: it gets really strange... it doesn't time out it just hangs.  If I debug and step through the problem everything works how I expect it too.  It only seems to be an issue switching to one particular iframe.  The only thing in this iframe... is a body tag with some onload javascript and another iframe inside it (it's SAP's BO autogenerated code, so I can't smack the devs around ask them wtf were they thinking?).

Comment: This is happening with the chromedriver.  IEDriver seems to handle it fine.

Comment: Yeah well I still haven't found a work  around for chrome or firefox. and it just seems the selenium library is broken.

Comment: I'm writing code for SAP's business objects generated html, it has a series of nested iFrames and one of them is nothing but a body tag with an onload javascript function and an iframe.  That's the iframe that just hangs when trying to switch too.  Not sure sure how easy it would be to reproduce reliably with out the whole Biz Object framework.

Comment: my guess is there's something funky in the javascript  or it has to do with the several nested iframes.